# Parsing Javascript variable to Python via Flask

Tags: javascript, python

I am currently working on a project that requires parsing variables from a javascript function every 5 ms to a python script that is running. I have an HTML server hosted with flask, but I can't seem to find a fairly simple way to get the variables into the python script. Here is the webpage I am trying to parse the data from: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/deviceorientationsample.html

I plan on having that run from the flask server which will also run the car with the data returned from the javascript variables. Any advice on a fairly easy setup would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your js needs to make ajax requests to a url on your flask server (probably not every 5ms but only when the variable change, too)

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work well if timing is important. The only way to get that data to the server code is with an HTTP request. Sending one every 5ms is not a good idea, and the request is not guaranteed to happen in a timely fashion.

This kind of quick back and forth is going to be best accomplished with websockets, in my opinion. Even then, 5ms is too quick to really accomplish something like this.

You may want to record the data in javascript and only send it to the server every x number of seconds using either websockets or AJAX.

Comment: Hmm I am using it to get the device orientation then I am sending that data to my pi to control a remote control car. What would you suggest for setting up a websocket?